# transition not working on first click

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

i have created that on click a div is showing with transition to the body. the problem is that on click the div is showing but without transition the second time i click the transition work.

i have this code:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navSelected" id="topNav">
            <li><a href="index.php" class="home"> HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php" class="about1"> ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php" class="service"> SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.php" class="newsNav"> NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="contact" id="contact"> CONTACT</a></li>


        </ul>
```

when clicking on the contact link the div opens so i created this for transition:

```
 if($('#contactUs').hasClass('moveNav')=== false){
      $('#contactUs').addClass('moveNav');
      $('body').css('width', '82vw');
      $('body').css('transition', 'all .4s ease-in-out');
      $('.navWidth').css('width', '82vw');
      $('.navWidth').css('transition', 'all .4s ease-in-out');
      $('.topSection .cover2').css('margin-right','100px');
      $('.topSection .cover2').css('transition','all .4s ease-in-out');
      $('.svgMarqueeDesign').css('margin','22px');
      $('.textCover').css('width','50%');
      }
```

and this is the div code:

```
<div id="contactUs" class="contactus">
<div class="text-right"><div id="close"></div>
```

```
    <div class="contactSvg">
        <svg class="menusvg1" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             width="75.325px" height="123.408px" viewBox="0 0 75.325 123.408" enable-background="new 0 0 75.325 123.408"
             xml:space="preserve">
```

```
    </div>
    <div class="text-center contactUsTitle">
        CONTACT US
    </div>


    <div id="contactUsForm">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="  contactUsInputs">

                <form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                               placeholder="First Name">

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control inputWidth" name="email" id="email1"
                               placeholder="E-mail Address">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control selectList required " id="selectList"  name="selectList"  >
                            <option value="">What is this about?</option>
                            <option value="firstchoice">first Choice</option>
                            <option value="secondchoice">second Choice</option>
                            <option value="thirdchoice">third Choice</option>
                            <option value="fourthchoice">fourth Choice</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group textArea1">
                        <textarea class="form-control inputWidth"  rows="10" name="about" id="about" placeholder="write your message here"></textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn learnMore send">send</button>

                    </div>
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

forget about the long code for the div but its not working from the first time,
only second time transition work thanks im advance

Comment: is the transition code initialized onload?

Comment: You should use all the above js code in `$(window).load(){}` event so it may work on load

Answer (score 0):

Your code is triggered when it it loaded. You have to bind it to the clicking of the menu https://jsfiddle.net/xj0s3a66/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contact").click(function() {
    if ($('#contactUs').hasClass('moveNav') === false) {
      $('#contactUs').addClass('moveNav');
      $('body').css('width', '82vw');
      $('body').css('transition', 'all .4s ease-in-out');
      $('.navWidth').css('width', '82vw');
      $('.navWidth').css('transition', 'all .4s ease-in-out');
      $('.topSection .cover2').css('margin-right', '100px');
      $('.topSection .cover2').css('transition', 'all .4s ease-in-out');
      $('.svgMarqueeDesign').css('margin', '22px');
      $('.textCover').css('width', '50%');
    }
  });
});
```